# Need to uninstall Ubuntu. Can't find partition in Windows 10

Tags: partitioning, vpn

I'm very confused.

I downloaded ubuntu and put it on a flash drive with `rufus`. I then installed it within boot manager and dual booted ubuntu. No problems.

But after I tried setting up my VPN and running `sudo apt-get upgrade` the log is spamming all kinds of errors.(also the vpn does not work)

I'm going to try reinstalling the OS but their are no new partitions on my HDD and when I installed ubuntu I never selected where to install it.

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the exact error messages.

Comment: Here is the end of the log http://pastebin.com/7ztyVnqQ

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you upgraded your distro to the beta version. You should re-install and re-setup. About the Windows 10 partition, you can try TestDisk to try to recover the lost partition. There are some other commercial products also. If you can't recover, if you have the serial, you can download Windows 10 directly from Microsoft. (Sometimes your notebook have a sticker with the serial bellow). Even if you are OEM, you can rebake the Windows DVD with a custom EI.cfg to accept OEM Channel.